# Detect retina images with javascript

Tags: javascript, image

I am trying to figure out a way to identify with javascript the "real" image width and height. As I am using a screenshot I took with Mac - the image size is double the actual size. It is 2560 x 1600 pixels instead of 1280 x 800 pixels. Is there a way for me to know what was the original size?

```
const image = new Image();
image.src = file.preview;
image.onload =  () =>  {
    console.log('width -> ', image.width);                  // 2560
    console.log('height -> ', image.height);                // 1600
    console.log('naturalWidth -> ', image.naturalWidth);    // 2560
    console.log('naturalHeight -> ', image.naturalHeight);  // 1600        
    }
```

***Update:***

Following @jontro suggestion I tried to investigate using

```
identifiy -verbose
```

A white 100x102 screenshot from a regular screen returned:

[image: regular]

While a white 101x100 screenshot for a retina screen returned:

[image: retina]

So the **resolution field** might be the right direction.

Comment: Are you sure the PNG contains this information? If so where would it be stored in the PNG? pHYs section?

Comment: Have a look at [the PNG file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) and use an appropriate `TypedArray` buffer to access the relevant bytes (should they exist). This looks like it is what you need: https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#11IHDR -- width/height are 4 byte unsigned integers.-- Example code: https://github.com/hughsk/png-chunks-extract (you need the IHDR chunk)

Comment: Just did a quick test on my macbook. From what I can see (using `identify -verbose`) the only thing that hints about a retina screen in the fields is the "resolution" type. I doubt the browsers can use this information

Comment: According [to the HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#dom-img-naturalwidth), the `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight` properties of the image object must return "the density-corrected intrinsic width and height of the image" (i.e. [image data dimensions divided by pixel density](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/images.html#density-corrected-intrinsic-width-and-height)). But the image itself doesn't "remember" at which pixel density it was made, so if measured at 1dppx it would behave as non-retina image (as your test shows).

Comment: Have a look at this project, https://github.com/arian/pngjs you should be able to parse the png in the browser using that :)

Comment: I will give it a try. Thanks!